# Connecting to Redis running in Docker Container from Host machine

Tags: docker, redis

I see lots of people struggling with this, sort of feel like maybe there is a bug in the redis container image, and others seem to be chasing a similar problem.

I'm using the standard redis image on DockerHub. (https://github.com/dockerfile/redis)

running it like this:

```
docker run -it -p 6379:6379 redis bash
```

Once I'm in I can start the server, and do a redis ping from the container image.

Unfortunately, I cannot connect to the redis container from my host.

I have tried setting, such as below.

```
bind 127.0.0.1
```

and removed the bind from the configuration

and tried turn off protected mode

```
protected-mode no
```

I know it is reading the configuration file, since I changed ports just to test, and I was able to do that.

I'm running Windows 10, so maybe it is a windows networking issue. I never have a problem with docker normally. I'm puzzled

Comment: How are you trying to connect to redis container? Are you trying to access bash inside redis container or trying to connect to redis container using 6379 port?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The problem is with your bind, You should set the following:

```
bind 0.0.0.0
```

This will set `redis` to bind to all interfaces available, in a containerized environment with one interface, (`eth0`) and a loopback (`lo`) redis will bind to both of the above. **You should consider adding security measures via other directives in `config file` or using external tools like `firewalls`. because with this approach everyone can connect to your `redis` server.**

The default setting is `bind 127.0.0.1` and this setting will cause `redis` to only listen on loopback interface, and it will be only accessible from inside the container. (for security)

To run redis with custom configuration file:

```
sudo docker run -d --name redis-test -p 6379:6379 \
     -v /path/to/redisconf/redis.conf:/redis.conf \
     redis redis-server /redis.conf
```

Now to verify on docker host with `redis-tools` installed:

```
redis-cli                           
127.0.0.1:6379> 
127.0.0.1:6379> set farhad likes:stackoverflow
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> get farhad
"likes:stackoverflow"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

You can also connnect to your `redis` container from an external host via:

```
redis-cli -h 'IP-address-of-dockerhost-running-redis-container'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, didn't quite get me there. It seems like Redis doesn't seem to like it when I try to connect from my host computer, but I spun up a second docker image, and got the IP address of the redis docker image, and I was able to connect. From a second docker image I was able to connect to the redis server like this: redis-cli -h 172.17.0.2

Comment: You should be able to connect to it if you can connect from another container. Just make sure your have `bind 0.0.0.0` in your custom config and you `expose 6378` when creating the container. from the docker hos your can connect by running `sudo redis-cli`. If all fails, give me step by step of what you are doing so I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks Farhad for your help. It seems to be something with the redis image on docker hub, I installed redis on an Ubuntu Server and it worked as I would have expected.I will just use that to hit redis from my local host

Comment: @FarhadFarahi thankyou. thankyou. thankyou. setting the bind has ended about 5 days of stress for me. ha

Comment: There should be a warning with big bold red letters before this answer "If you only apply this, your server will get hacked".

Comment: @pkExec maybe try to read the answer before copy pasting? "You should consider adding security measures via other directives in config file or using external tools like firewalls. because with this approach everyone can connect to your redis server.", I can make it bold if it helps, but not red :)

Comment: In my test, seems, by default, docker container is accessible from remote, as long as your map port to host.

Answer (score 79):

This is simpler way to set up a Redis container.

### Download image and run container

```
docker run -d --name some-redis -p 6379:6379 redis
```

If you don't have the image, this command will pull it. And then, if you need to access from **redis-cli** to console, can use:

```
docker exec -it some-redis bash
```

For enter to container console, and kind in the console:

```
root@72c388dc2cb8:/data# redis-cli
```

Output:

```
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

This was enough for my use case (easy and fast local development).

Comment: This looks like a good solution! I was able to open `redis-cli` directly by running the following command `docker exec -it some-redis redis-cli` and skip over the `bash` step.

Comment: This is totally the opposite of what was asked in the question. He wants to connect to the redis-server running in a container from the host environment (on which the container is running). That is, if you started a redis container on your linux machine, he wants to access it from the linux machine and not from inside the redis container.

Comment: @cyphx if you run your redis container mapping the port from your localhost (where you are running redis) then you should be able to connect from the host environment.

Answer (score 8):

It might be easier now with version `4.0.9` (`Docker Toolbox on Win10`). Simply connect with a redis client, then:

```
set bind 0.0.0.0
save
```

The new setting sticks after stop/start.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some instructions to make this work properly.

### Install Official Docker not Distro repo.

```
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
sudo sh get-docker.sh
systemctl enable docker ; systemctl start docker; systemctl status docker
```

Refer to [Install using the convenience script](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#install-using-the-convenience-script)

### Connect to Redis container from host

```
mkdir -p /etc/redis/
chown -R 1000:1000 /etc/redis
sudo docker run -d --name redis -p 6379:6379 --restart unless-stopped -v /etc/redis/:/data redis redis-server /data
```

NOTE: The important part that is key to your solution is to have port expose (-p 6379:6379) to your docker host and route to container port.
Refer to [Redis Docker Documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/)

### Install "redis-tools" in your docker host. Centos install redis via epel release.

Answer (score 4):

create Redis container using below command

```
sudo docker run -d --name redis-test -p 6379:6379  -v /redis/redis.conf:/redis.conf redis redis-server /redis.conf --appendonly yes --requirepass "redis"
```

you can access the Redis in the same machine using `Redis-CLI` and if you are using other machines use `host machine IP`. if you are accessing Redis container in the same host another docker container uses the `private IP` of the machine.

Answer (score 1):

**In case you want to run Redis Cluster in docker containers.**

The answer is in the Redis self-documented `redis.conf` file and here is an extract from the file on how to solve the problem like a pro.

All credits to the redis.conf file, redis version 6 and above.

```
########################## CLUSTER DOCKER/NAT support  ########################

# In certain deployments, Redis Cluster nodes address discovery fails, because
# addresses are NAT-ted or because ports are forwarded (the typical case is
# Docker and other containers).
#
# In order to make Redis Cluster working in such environments, a static
# configuration where each node knows its public address is needed. The
# following two options are used for this scope, and are:
#
# * cluster-announce-ip
# * cluster-announce-port
# * cluster-announce-bus-port
#
# Each instructs the node about its address, client port, and cluster message
# bus port. The information is then published in the header of the bus packets
# so that other nodes will be able to correctly map the address of the node
# publishing the information.
#
# If the above options are not used, the normal Redis Cluster auto-detection
# will be used instead.
#
# Note that when remapped, the bus port may not be at the fixed offset of
# clients port + 10000, so you can specify any port and bus-port depending
# on how they get remapped. If the bus-port is not set, a fixed offset of
# 10000 will be used as usual.
#
# Example:
#
# cluster-announce-ip 10.1.1.5
# cluster-announce-port 6379
# cluster-announce-bus-port 6380
```

Answer (score 1):

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  redis_1:
    image: 'redis:6.0.6'
    ports:
      - '6371:6379'
  redis_2:
    image: 'redis:6.0.6'
    ports:
      - '6372:6379'
```

In your host machine:

```
docker compose up
```

```
redis-cli -p 6371 ping
redis-cli -p 6372 ping
```

Answer (score 0):

Found many articles, questions, github-issues about not being able to connect from Windows host to redis running as a docker container on wsl2, with many suggested fixes involving IP mappings. However, with recent (2022-ish) versions of wsl2 and redis image I had a similar issue but the fix was simple.
I was using `docker-compose` and skeleton setup was

```
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:7.0
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data
```

but, as copy and paste from a non-WSL docker environment, I also had

```
    network_mode: host
```

and that was preventing me from connecting from the Windows host to the container running under WSL. As soon as I removed that line, docker created a default network for the service and I could connect (using `127.0.0.1:6379`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WSL2 from Windows and running redis in Docker or Podman,

- Get and run the podman container (replace with docker if docker):

  podman run -d  --rm --name redis_server -v redis-data:/var/redis/data -p 6379:6379 redis

The above command creates and mounts persistent volume called redis-data (if doesn't exist) and expose it over port 6379

- Get the ip address in your WSL2 Ubuntu/Pengwin using `ifconfig -a`, for example.
- Use the IP and port to connect to redis-insight from your Windows machine

[image]