# How to connect to dockerized Redis Server?

Tags: docker, macos, networking, redis, macos-monterey

I am unable to connect (timeout) to a dockerized redis server<sup>1</sup> which was started with the command of:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 6379:6379 redis:alpine
```

I've tried to start the server [with configs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41371402/7032856):

```
set bind to 0.0.0.0
protected-mode no
```

I am however able to connect to my redis server with another docker container with the following command:

```
docker run -it --rm redis:alpine redis-cli -h host.docker.internal -p 6379
```

and also tried [configuring the same parameters through cli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50384099/7032856) as well.

When I try to connect the connection times out, I tried with both internal ip

```
172.17.0.x
```

and with the internal domain name:

```
host.docker.internal
```

to no avail. Further note that I was able to connect to redis server when installed with

```
brew install redis
```

on the host.

What am I missing, how can I resolve the issue so that I can connect to redis-server that is within a docker container from the container's host?

---

###### Environment details

```
OS: MacOS Monterey Version: 12.6 (21G115)

Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
```

---

<sup>1 <sub>More specifically I've tried with both
[`rdcli -h host.docker.internal`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-cli) in the mac terminal and also on application side with [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis).</sub></sup>

Comment: which command is giving you the error or timeout? Can you provide complete example. Also, from where are you running that command (container or your laptop)?

Comment: @usuario I think those are already explained in the answer but still I've edited to include more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> More specifically I've tried with both rdcli -h host.docker.internal in the mac terminal

The `host.docker.internal` is a DNS name to access the docker host from inside a container. It's a bad practice to use this inside one container to talk to another container. Instead you'd create a network, create both containers in that network, and use the container name to connect. When that's done, the port doesn't even need to be published.

From the host, that's when you connect to the published port. Since the container is deployed with `-p 6379:6379`, you should be able to access that port from the hostname of your host, or localhost on that host:

```
rdcli -h localhost
```